# GAE - how to create a private url that is only used by the application?

Tags: ajax, security, google-app-engine, private

Using GAE with Python for this project.

I am creating a page with a chart of statistics that updates(refreshes) itself (every 10 sec) using AJAX. It is my first time using AJAX.
What I am thinking is, that I should create a private page that will give the needed information for the statistics chart. Then I simply get the info using AJAX.

Is that the way to go about it? If so how do I make a private page in GAE, I don't want users to be able to go to that page.. Thanks

What are the security concerns for a production quality application?

Comment: What you're asking for is fundamentally impossible: if your user's browser can make a valid request and interpret it, so can your user. Why would you want to do this, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [require a login](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status) for your private page and your AJAX handler and set the login level to `admin`. You may require a login for one or more Urls.

**Edit**

Set `login: required`, which will require users to login via their Google Accounts, but still all users with Google Accounts will be able to access it. Then in the AJAX handler check if the user is one of the users that you have given access to: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/

Comment: But if I want normal users to see the charts? How will I use AJAX to login without giving leaving the login info exposed in the JavaScript code?

Comment: So you only want _some_ users to have access? Then you need to write code that checks if a user accessing this url is one of the users you had in mind.

Comment: I think this answers my question so:
(1). -~ Any information I AJAX from the code is also available in raw form if the users looks in the javascript code and goes to the url. -~ Is that correct
(2). -~ I can limit information I access with AJAX from my JavaScript code only to people who have google accounts.
(3). -~ So I cannot AJAX info that I also want to be password protected and private.

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. Yes, but you can add additional checks in your AJAX handler to allow only particular people

Comment: 3. There is no "private" data in Javascript. Once you send data to browser, user can see it if they know where to look.

Comment: One way around this is to try to obscure the data. One quite effective way is to generate images containing graphs on server.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is simply Javascript sending HTTP requests. From a server point of view, there is no way to differentiate between user requests and Javascript requests. So there is no such thing as "private page".

Comment: So if the user knows the page url, she can access the JSON that she is not supposed to?

Comment: Indeed. I see no secure way around that. Maybe you can somewhat obfuscate your data and rework them in Javascript client side, but it's still "public".

Comment: so the best I can do.. is hope they don't go to that page? and never send any secure info using AJAX? Is that correct? Or is there some way to password protect it?

Comment: Even if you password-protect it, the authentication informations are still in your javascript code for everyone to see. Why you don't want them to go that page anyway? Aren't they supposed to see you charts?

Comment: Well, they can see the data that I've created as a chart.. I don't want them to gain access to raw data. Only to the charts

Comment: Then make it so your "AJAX page" computes and returns the chart data, not the raw data :)